# PowerShell Module not Discovered

Tags: powershell, module

I have a PowerShell module that I have created and is installed in the WindowsPowerShell\Modules path. I can auto-discover the module if it installed in the root of the module folder, example WindowsPowerShell\Modules\NewModule, however if I create a sub-folder in the module folder, the module is not long auto-discovered, example WindowsPowerShell\Modules\NewModule\1.0.

Why would the module stop being auto-discovered by adding the module and manifest to a sub-folder in the Module folder? I have plenty of modules using this structure that auto-discover fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why the others are working, I'm guessing it's how PS installed the module depending on where it's sourced from (i.e. modules installed from PSGallery typically are in a version subfolder). Per the MS docs on installing modules though, the parent module folder should be directly in your module path in order for it to be recognized correctly as a module:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx

That being said, if you're creating modules and storing them all in a subfolder in your PSModulePath, you should be fine just updating your PSModulePath environment variable to include that subfolder as well. Once done, reload your PS session and retry your import.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you know why the modules installed from the gallery would auto-discover in a version subfolder without having to update the PSModulePath variable?